How can we implement LIM models from huggingface using langchain_huggingface library?
Langchain_Huggingface released recently in May 2024.I implemented some open source LLM using the same library (langchain_huggingface). That worked well. But now I am trying to generate images but couldn't figure it out.
"lim = HuggingFaceEndpoint(repo_id="  ",task="text-to-image",token= key)"
I tried to make an endpoint but didn't work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
